# Sorting by distance on a numeric field in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

For a project I need to select documents which are within filter bounds and a closest to a numeric value. This is about a price and I cannot seem to find if this is possible.

Say I have 2 documents:

```
{
    "name": "Document1",
    "price": 46.12,
    "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"]
}
{
    "name": "Document2",
    "price": 82.29,
    "tags": ["tag1", "tag3"]
}
```

Is it possible to get the document with the price closest to 66.23?

Comment: if dynamic_scripting is enabled in your cluster you could use script based sorting : sorting based on the absolute difference http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting

Comment: It wasn't, but I enabled it as ES is only accessable through private parts of our software so it seemed relatively safe enough to do so. I use it currently like this:

    {
        "query": {
        ...
        },
        "sort" : {
            "_script" : {
                "script" : "cur = (factor - doc['Payload.age'].value); if (cur < 0) { cur = cur * -1 } else { cur = cur}",
                "type" : "number",
                "params" : {
                    "factor" : 45
                },
                "order" : "asc"
            }
        }
    }

Answer (score 5):

The answer (thanks to keety) was to enable dynamic scripting and add a sorting method like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered" : {
            "query":{
                "match_all" : { }
            },
            "filter": {}
        }
    },
    "sort" : {
        "_script" : {
            "script" : "cur = (factor - doc['age'].value); if (cur < 0) { cur = cur * -1 } else { cur = cur}",
            "type" : "number",
            "params" : {
                "factor" : 45
            },
            "order" : "asc"
        }
    }
}
```

This sorts from closest to farthest and works like a charm. Thanks!