# Elasticsearch near value query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 100 documents with field price between 1000 and 10,000

For example: I want to query 4 documents with prices near 5000, the expected values can be more or less 5000.

If I set ranges it might give me empty results sometimes because it found not results between my max and min values.

I can requery it with larger min and max values but I don't think it is the correct solution.

Also I've tried [Span queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/span-queries.html) but it does n't support numeric values

Is there any way to do this in elasticsearch 6.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways I can think of doing it.

1: Do a `range query` over price equal to 5000 plus or minus some constant. Add `sort` in your query based on their distance from given price (5000 in your case). [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616687/sorting-by-distance-on-a-numeric-field-in-elasticsearch)

2: Use `function_score` to compute the score of each match in a range query with a function dedicated to compute the absolute distance from price 5000. [Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)